# Postgresql in Active Directory Machine

Tags: postgresql, dns, active-directory

I have a server in which Postgresql is installed. In this server I want to install the Microsoft Active Directory. Can I do this without a problems? Can I change the user that runs the Postgresql service without a problem?

When I install the AD all the machine users will be deleted so I need to create domain users to run that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work, but there could be performance issues since you're basically running two databases on the same machine.

It's a risk that the upgrade will remove the PostgreSQL service user. In this case, you will jus thave to create a new one and assign it to the service. Another option is to uninstall PostgreSQL (this will not uninstall the data), turn the machine into an AD controller, and then reinstall PostgreSQL (same version!). It will then pick up the old data directory automatically.